# how to return more than one value in sql server isnull function

Tags: isnull

```
and area.ID in (ISNULL(@area, (select ID from Areas where AreaTypeId = 3)))
```

i use a parameter @area in where condition to get information about specified area id, but if the user doesn't inter area id all information for all areas will appear. but i have an error message appear when run the query:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

KIndly help me if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix is to just return `@area` in your subquery if it is specified:

```
and area.ID in (select ISNULL(@area, ID) from Areas where AreaTypeId = 3)
```

You may be able to do it more efficiently without the sub-query, but not sure without seeing your full query. Something like:

```
select * Area
    where (@area is not null and area.ID = @area)
    or (@area is null and area.AreaTypeId = 3)
```